# I can't export a custom report name from html-reporter-extra

Tags: windows, jenkins, newman

This really should be straightforward but I can't get it to work.
It's a simple setup: I have a locally run Jenkins, exported Postman collections that I'm running using newman. I got html-report-extra installed and it's generating a report but I can't get it to export the html file under a different name!
I have a locally installed Jenkins, I'm using a freestyle project and under Build - Execute Windows batch command I have this:

```
newman run IDMS4.postman_collection.json -e IDMS4.postman_environment.json --reporters cli,htmlextra --reporter-html-export newman/index.html --disable-unicode
```

This is how my Jenkins job is setup:
[Jenkins job setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih9tG.png)

Build completes but there is no index.html anywhere. This is the the part that's puzzling me.
In

> .jenkins\jobs\Newman runner\htmlreports\HTMLReport

i get the default file format name (project name + timestamp).
In

> .jenkins\workspace\Newman runner\newman

I also get project name + timestamp html files.

Why is this outputed to both folders and how can I get this to export just one index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with dot slash.  **eg:** ./newman/index.html.

and also
if you need collection name to be in the report, please use following node module

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/jaiman

Comment: Hello @jayanth-bala. I used your product. But it is not possible to send the report to my smtp server because it is impossible to enter authorization data. Could you please share the source code to fix or fix this issue?

Comment: Or post it on github as newman?